# AngularJS - Update Model after $resource, using same controller with "this" or $scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code:

```
// States with same templates and a param to know the difference

[...]
.state('concluded', {
    url: '/concluded',
    params: { type: 'concluded' },
    parent: 'aggregators',
    templateUrl: 'views/aggregators/index.html',
    controller: 'AggregatorsCtrl'
})
.state('pending', {
    url: '/pending',
    params: { type: 'pending' },
    parent: 'aggregators',
    templateUrl: 'views/aggregators/index.html',
    controller: 'AggregatorsCtrl'
}
[...]

// Controller
var vm = this;
var type = $state.params.type;
vm.processos = [];

$scope.$watch(type, function () {    
    if (type === 'concluded') {
        getConcludedProcesses();
    } else if (type === 'pending') {
        getPendingProcesses();
    }
});

function getPendingProcesses() {
    // Resource call
    ProcessesService.getProcessosPendentes({ qtdDias: 12 }, function (response) {
        updateProcessos(response);
    });
}

function updateProcessos(response) {
    var processos = [];
    angular.forEach(response, function (e, key) {
        processos.push({
            [..]
        });
    });
    vm.processos = processos;
}
```

**Question**: When I'm on the state *pending* for the first time everything loads ok and the views are updated. When I change the state to *concluded* and update *vm.processos* variable the view is not updated. However, when I changed the *vm.processos* to *$scope.processos* the view is updated. What is the problem and the difference to use ***this*** instead of ***$scope*** in the question context?

I'm trying to use *this* instead of *$scope* to model variables following the best practices of Angular.

**Edit 1**:

I'm using Controller as synthax when with *this* way.

```
ng-controller="AggregatorsCtrl as aggregator"
[...]
ng-repeat="processo in aggregator.processos"
[...]
```

Comment: Do you need to use `controller: 'AggregatorsCtrl as vm'` when setting up your states?

Comment: Sorry, i get your comment now. I'm not using as vm in the states setup, but i've tryed now and didnot work.